# What the fastest way to pass large data between JVMs?

Tags: java, data, spring, jvm

I have 2 JVMs on the same machine that I want to pass about 1Mb of (serializable) data between ideally in under 5 ms.

Under load, using HTTP to localhost takes about 70ms average.

I tried hazelcast, passing the data via a distributed queue - about 50ms average.

Is there a faster way?

---

I'm using spring boot.

Comment: Does "under load" mean that the receiving thread might not even get scheduled for 70ms because you have more computation heavy threads than CPU cores?

Comment: @codes good question: the benchmark I created does no processing, it just receives and returns a big string. I'm using (about) half the cores to send and half to receive.

Comment: While there are certainly faster transports than http on localhost, it still shouldn't be anywhere that slow.

Comment: @CodesInChaos hmmm. You made me think about how many threads I had on *both* sides, and it had too many. My throughput with *less* processing threads on the listening side and less on the sending side gave results of about 10ms with 600+ TPS. Which is acceptable. I'm still going to try memory mapped file for interest sake.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use pure sockets?

A socket on the same machine will send data over pretty quickly.
Assuming you can send 100 MB\s over, you should be able to send 1 MB
in roughly 10 ms. Getting higher speeds than this will be a bit
tricky. If you had a good card you could get it to under 5 ms.

If you can serialize the data, you can send it over quite easily. See [this](http://www.coderpanda.com/java-socket-programming-transferring-of-java-objects-through-sockets/) for sending objects over sockets.

Using files would give you an average of about 80-160 MB/s or 12 ms - 6.25 ms to send 1 MB, but you'd have to read it again which will take more time.

You could use a [Memory-mapped file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) to only have to read the file once and have it stored in memory so any virtual machine could read it from memory. Keeping a file in memory with a [MappedByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) will provide efficient access but you'd have to read the file first. This is also a bit more complicated than sending over sockets or writing to/reading from a file.